# QListWidget clear method

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have item and itemWidget in my QListWidget. I want to delete all items and all items widgets. I try delete them like that:

```
lstWdgs->clear();
```

But i am not sure, that it deletes items and itemWidgets correctly

Comment: The documentation is clear in this case: "The list widget will take ownership of the item."

Comment: @chehrlic This means that item will be deleted, but I don't understand whether the itemWidgets will be deleted too or not

Comment: Looks like the note is missing - for QTreeWidget it's there - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget : "Note: The tree takes ownership of the widget."

Comment: @chehrlic The ownership guarantees the items and item widgets to be deleted when the list widget (specifically the viewport) is deleted, but not when `clear()` is called

Answer (score 2):

The items and item widgets are destroyed when `clear()` is called. It can be tested by using the `destroyed()` signal for item widgets, and overriding the destructor of `QListWidgetItem` for items.

Example code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include <QDebug>

class ListWidgetItem : public QListWidgetItem
{
public:
    explicit ListWidgetItem(const QString &text) : QListWidgetItem(text) {}
    ~ListWidgetItem()
    {
        qDebug() << this->text() << "destroyed";
    }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QListWidget *list_widget = new QListWidget;
    ListWidgetItem *list_widget_item = new ListWidgetItem{tr("Item 1")};
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton{tr("Button")};
    connect(button, &QObject::destroyed, this, []()
    {
        qDebug() << "Button destroyed";
    });
    connect(list_widget->viewport(), &QObject::destroyed, this, []()
    {
        qDebug() << "Viewport destroyed";
    });

    list_widget->addItem(list_widget_item);
    list_widget->addItem(new ListWidgetItem{tr("Item 2")});
    list_widget->addItem(new ListWidgetItem{tr("Item 3")});
    list_widget->setItemWidget(list_widget->item(2), button);

    QPushButton *clear_button = new QPushButton{tr("Clear list")};
    connect(clear_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [list_widget]()
    {
        qDebug() << "Clearing list";
        list_widget->clear();
    });
    QPushButton *delete_button = new QPushButton{tr("Delete list")};
    connect(delete_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]()
    {
        qDebug() << "Deleting list";
        delete list_widget;
        delete_button->setDisabled(true);
        clear_button->setDisabled(true);
    });


    QWidget *central_widget = new QWidget{this};
    this->setCentralWidget(central_widget);
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout{central_widget};
    layout->addWidget(list_widget);
    layout->addWidget(clear_button);
    layout->addWidget(delete_button);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

The output after clicking the clear button is:

> Clearing list
> "Item 1" destroyed
> "Item 2" destroyed
> "Item 3" destroyed
> Button destroyed

As to how this happens, we can look into Qt's source code

1. `clear()` deletes the items, and calls `endResetModel()`, [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qlistwidget.cpp.html#_ZN10QListModel5clearEv)
2. `endResetModel()` emits `modelReset()`, [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp.html#_ZN18QAbstractItemModel13endResetModelEv)
3. `modelReset()` connected to view's `reset()`, [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#743)
4. View's `reset()` releases the editors (widgets) in `indexEditorHash`, deleting the widgets, [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView5resetEv)
5. `indexEditorHash` stores the widget in `setIndexWidget()` by calling `addEditor()`, [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView14setIndexWidgetERK11QModelIndexP7QWidget)
6. `setIndexWidget()` called by `setItemWidget()`, [source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qlistwidget.cpp.html#_ZN11QListWidget13setItemWidgetEP15QListWidgetItemP7QWidget)

Comment: What a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

The docs say "All items will be permanently deleted.".
Extra hint: Why not debug into your dtor of `item` and `itemWidget` to see what happens?